# How do I format a date without a leading zero in month?

Tags: c#, date, datetime, formatting, leading-zero

The code is

```
time.ToString("yyyyMMddHmmsFFF"));
```

And it returns "20190121153530" with leading zero after 2019.

How do I format the date to get "2019121153530" without the leading zero?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: Why would you want to do that? There are mutlple pairs of dates that would result in the same string representation according to your requirment. An example: One is the date 2019121, and the other is the date 2019121. One is 21st of January. The other is 1st of December. Now try figuring out which is which. I would rather program in [Brainfuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) than dealing with such a mess... ;-P

Comment: @elgonzo it's extremely good notice. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`MM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#MM_Specifier) in the format you specified will use "The month, from 01 through 12".

[`M`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#M_Specifier) in the format will use "The month, from 1 through 12". Such as:

```
time.ToString("yyyyMddHmmsFFF"));
```

See "[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#table)" for more options on `DateTime` string formatting.

Comment: But I’m afraid that you won’t be able to parse it back.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes, thanks. But the question how do I do this better is outside this topic.